# Simulate app loading with HTML 5 progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar

I am aiming for a loading progress bar that fluctuates in speed as it goes from 0 to 100%. I would like some variety in the way it loads to give the appearance of loading my app. The following code sorta gets me there, but just not with the variety I was looking for.

Any suggestions on how to improve upon or completely reconstruct this?

UPDATE:

I have altered the code myself to achieve what I'm looking for.

Here's a fiddle: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/e010vo1c/1/)

```
var counter = 0; var factor = 1;
var timer = setInterval(function () { // timer function for progress bar
counter = counter + factor;

$('.progressbar').val(counter);
    if (counter >= 10 && counter <= 59) {
        damping = Math.floor(Math.random() * (300 - 25)) + 6;
        factor = Math.max((100 - counter) / damping, '0.5');
    } else if (counter >= 60 && counter < 100) {
        damping = Math.floor(Math.random() * (50 - 25)) + 3;
        factor = Math.max((100 - counter) / damping, '0.5');
    } else if (counter > 100) {
        clearInterval(timer);
    };
}, 30);
```

Comment: Are you actually loading data or you just doing this for appearances? If its just for appearances I would advise against it as having a loading screen just for the sake of it is annoying for some users. If you are actually wanting to load data you should base the timer off when each part of the data is done loading.

Comment: Yes, this is strictly for appearance.

Comment: Can you share a fiddle?